# Android. ART for loop optimization bug. Simple java function with unexpected result

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, dalvik, android-5.1.1-lollipop

**EDIT:**
After many hours of testing I can say that this is a **serious bug** of the ART Android Runtime with for loops.

Yesterday I found a glitch in our game, and when debugging the code found that a very simple java function was getting unexpected results (depending on the Android version of the device).
This is the java code:

```
// Simple function to count items of a 6 rows pyramid (1+2+3+4+5+6)
private int getSum ()
{
    int sum=0, x=0;
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) { x++; sum+=x; }
    return sum;   // always should return 21
}
```

To test it just add this line of code to your existing Android project in the OnCreate function:

```
    Log.d("@@@ Test", "getSum=" + getSum());
```

If your Android is <strike>5.1.1 or</strike> 6.0.x it will show 15 (ERROR result), if it's a previous Android version it will return 21 (OK result).

Please, can someone do this simple test. I'm getting mad about this.

If you debug step-by-step the code then it returns the correct value (21). If you try to trace the code it also returns 21 value.
Example:

```
private int getSum2 ()
{
    int sum=0, x=0;
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++) { x++; Log.d ("@@@ Test","x="+x); sum+=x; }
    return sum;   // always should return 21
}
```

getSum2 works ok always (just adding a Log.d).

What I'm missing? This is driving me nuts.
I'm not using proguard.
I think this can be an optimization related bug of the ART runtime.

Thanks in advance.

David.

Comment: I have tested in jellybean and lollipop devices I got 21 both the times.

Comment: Thank you very much!. Maybe it's a Marshmallow issue (?)

Comment: Please, can someone do this simple test in Android 6.0.x. Thanks.

Comment: Yes @Daviddev I've tested in android 6.0.1 its giving 15. Very strange.

Comment: Thank you @Raghavendra! I think this is really a serious bug. It may have many unwanted behaviours. I opened an issue (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215604), but still no replies.

Comment: okay lets see someone will respond.

Comment: any updates @Daviddev.?

Comment: Seems, that has been fixed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37109606